# Query will not update table in subform MS-Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

I created a table in MS-Access 2010 by running the following script on SQL server 2008

```
SELECT * into qryInstrumentInterfacelog FROM tblInstrumentInterfaceLog
```

qryInstrumentInterface is used to populate a subform on the main form.  After a "Process" button is pressed, files are read in and stored in the database.  tblInstrumentInterface will be inserted with a new record everytime a new file is read in.  My problem is qryInstrumentInterfacelog will not update with tblInstrumentInterfaceLog, it will just keep the same data it had when the script was first ran on the server.  I have tried different methods to requery the subform but I realized the subform had no issues it was the actual table that wasn't changing.  How can I get qryInstrumentInterfacelog to be dynamic and update as tblInstrumentInterfaceLog updates? Is my SQL code wrong?

Comment: What calls the SQL code?

Comment: I ran it on the server and saved it as a table, then linked it to Access, I didn't really call it

Comment: Ok, so it's a linked table?

Comment: yes, the database is stored on the SQL server

Comment: So is the table in SQL server being updated as expected?  Is it just the Access linked table that is not being updated?

Comment: no the SQL server table is not being updated, it keeps the values it had when it was first executed

Comment: By what process do you add data into that table?

Comment: I call a stored procedure to insert data into tblInstrumentInterfaceLog then I want to somehow requery qryinstrumentInterfacelog to refresh the table being displayed in the subform on my main form

Comment: If the new data isn't getting into tblInstrumentInterfaceLog, then it sounds like your stored procedure doesn't work.  What is the SP definition?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one important concern is that, indeed, you cannot repeat the query as written.

"Select... into" creates a new table only.  It does not insert/append to such a table.
So if you are really calling that a second time, it is probably erroring out.

If you really want to drop and replace the table, make sure to call an explicit "Drop Table" in advance of your "Select...Into".

--
A typical pattern, in SQL Server t-sql, is

```
if object_id('*your_table_name*') is not null  
  drop table *your_table_name*
;  
*...your select...into*
```

Comment: So I should make it a store procedure, add the drop table line and then call it when I want to refresh the table?