# Access 2010 subform table not displaying all records in assigned Record Source

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, subform

I am working in a database with an Access 2010 frontend and SQL server 2008 backend.  I created a subform that will display all records in a particular query.  A stored procedure is used to create and refresh the query anytime new records are added.  Here is the stored procedure that refreshes and creates the table.

```
Create Procedure ReqryInstrumentInterfacelog As
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
       WHERE TABLE_NAME='qryInstrumentInterfacelog')
BEGIN
    DROP table qryInstrumentInterfacelog
END
SELECT * into qryInstrumentInterfacelog 
FROM tblInstrumentInterfaceLog
GO
```

My problem is my subform will only display the new record added and all previous records in the table will not be displayed.  this is strange because when I check the table created by the query it shows all the records in it.  I did not have this problem previously until I  added a Parent-child link.  I am following a spec and one of the instructions is to add specific master/child links in the properties of the subform.  Once I added those all previous records will not display.  But i feel like i need these links because it makes it so that when you open the form the subform is empty until you fill in certain fields.  Then when you press a "process files' button logic is done and the subform is filled.   Another issue with the parent/child link is in my given spec it tells me to make certain controls and fields the links but when I press the three dot button and it gives me options for master/child links, it doesn't not give those fields as an option so I just type them in manually.  Does this mean those fields are not able to be links? I'm sure I left out something so feel free to ask for more information. My question is: Is there something wrong with the way I wrote my stored procedure or does it probably have to do with my property settings and child/parent link issues.
UPDATE: spec I am trying to follow[image]

Even though I was given instructions in the spec, I was told I have the freedom to modify the instructions at my own discretion

Comment: What about [Requery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195253(v=office.15).aspx)?

Comment: First question is: Why are you using a query that does nothing more than return all records in tblInstrumentInterfacelog? Just base your subform on tblInstrumentInfterfaceLog instead.

Master/child links are used to relate subform records with a single masterform record, so you must be careful to set those correctly. Basically, the "master" link is the Primary Key field of the main form, and the "child" link is the Foreign Key field in the subform (the field that stores that PK value).

Comment: I am following a spec and I was told to create a qry, i am not sure myself why it is necessary. Also in a previous question I asked someone told me to create a store procedure. I will include the instructions from the spec in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616584/query-will-not-update-table-in-subform-ms-access